# Can't push image to Amazon ECR - fails with "no basic auth credentials"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-ecr

I'm trying to push a docker image to an Amazon ECR registry. I'm using docker client Docker version 1.9.1, build `a34a1d5`. I use `aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1` to get the docker login creds. Then I successfully login with those creds as follows:

```
docker login -u AWS -p XXXX -e none https://####.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
WARNING: login credentials saved in /Users/ar/.docker/config.json
Login Succeeded
```

But when I try to push my image I get the following error:

```
$ docker push ####.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/image:latest
The push refers to a repository [####.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/image] (len: 1)
bcff5e7e3c7c: Preparing 
Post https://####.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/image/blobs/uploads/: no basic auth credentials
```

I made sure that the aws user had the correct permissions. I also made sure that the repository allowed that user to push to it. Just to make sure that wasn't an issue I set the registry to allow all users full access. Nothing changes the `"no basic auth credentials"` error. I don't know how to begin to debug this since all the traffic is encrypted.

**UPDATE**

So I had a bit of Homer Simpson D'Oh moment when I realized the root cause of my problem. I have access to multiple AWS accounts. Even though I was using `aws configure` to set my credentials for the account where I had setup my repository the aws cli was actually using the environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. So when I did `aws ecr get-login` it was returning a login for the wrong account. I failed to notice that the account numbers were different until I just went back now to try some of the proposed answers. When I remove the environment variables everything works correctly. I guess the motto of the story is if you hit this error, make sure that the repository you are logging into matches the tag you have applied to the image.

Comment: The same error is given when the repository does not exist. Check whether you created the repo in the right region.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/common-errors-docker.html#error-403

Comment: Note that you can set up your aws cli to handle multiple user profiles: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html

Comment: I agree that update should be in giant bold letters. Spent way too long trying all the wrong things, when this was the silly solution that fixed it for me.

Comment: I had this error when i was not paying attention to the region i am logged in.

Comment: I would suggest aws-vault, if you have access to multiple accounts and switch accounts simultaneously.

Comment: this for me was a whif in the end. my script was running docker push as root, so i just copied the credentials from my user/.docker to /root

Comment: I forgot about the AWS_PROFILE variable.  The `default` one in my ~/.aws/config file did not have the right permissions.  Spent hours trying to get this to work with the various config providers.  What a waste of time haha!

Answer (score 241):

if you run `$(aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1)` it will be all done for you

### Update July 2021:

`get-login` is now deprecated in version 1 of the AWS CLI. If you're using version 2 of the AWS CLI, you must use `get-login-password`.

You can pipe the output of `get-login-password` to your docker login command to authenticate docker to your ECR registry:

```
aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ####.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Now you should be able to `docker push` and have it go straight to your ECR registry.

Comment: You're a legend. AWS guide had 5 steps all with a shell command except for step 2, which only say "Run the docker login command that was returned in the previous step." I guess a whole heap of people like myself just focus on the shell command and didn't read the instruction properly

Comment: Time machine - Why does wrapping the aws command in $() cause the login to succeed correctly?

Comment: @VtoCorleone Because the aws command just prints a docker command to the standard output. If you wrap that string in $(), it will be interpreted by the shell and the `docker login` command will be run.

Comment: $(aws ecr get-login --region us-west-2)
unknown shorthand flag: 'e' in -e
See 'docker login --help'.

Comment: @TienDinh why it's not working for me ? jenkins@ip-172-31-22-20:~/workspace/qa_global_pp_docker$ $(aws ecr get-login --region us-west-2)
unknown shorthand flag: 'e' in -e
See 'docker login --help'. ................$ cat ~/.aws/config
[default]
output = text
region = us-west-2

Comment: $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2) .....cool thnks Antonio Terreno You're a legend.

Comment: if you're getting "unknown shorthand flag: 'e'", you must run the command with the --no-include-email flag like this: $(aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1 --no-include-email)

Comment: as @kenorb points out, if you have multiple profiles you need to pass `--profile` as well to get this to work correctly. In my case the combination of profile and wrapping the command in `$()` did the trick.

Comment: as of 2020 get-login is deprecated, use get-login-password instead. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login.html

Comment: This is not recommend since this expose authorisation key to terminal, instead use docker login as recommended in AWS. detailed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689445/cant-push-image-to-amazon-ecr-fails-with-no-basic-auth-credentials/65422039#65422039

Comment: This worked for me. You can also use this in github actions with AWS credentials

Comment: remember to set `--region` flag when calling `aws ecr get-login-password`

Answer (score 66):

### **Update**

Since AWS CLI version 2 - `aws ecr get-login` is deprecated and the correct method is [`aws ecr get-login-password`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login-password.html).

Therefore the correct and updated answer is the following:
`docker login -u AWS -p $(aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1) xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

Comment: I get `unknown flag: --region`

Comment: @kittu works for me. which aws cli version are you using?

Comment: You are amazing

Comment: @kittu `--region` is an AWS CLI option, not a Docker option

Answer (score 63):

In my case this was a bug with Docker for Windows and their support for the Windows Credential Manager.

Open your `~/.docker/config.json` and remove the `"credsStore": "wincred"` entry.

This will cause credentials to be written to the `config.json` directly. You'll have to log in again afterwards.

You can track this bug through the tickets [#22910](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22910) and [#24968](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/24968) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks - worked on Windows 10. After removing that property from config, and running docker login command again, the config file was updated with credentials, and push worked.

Comment: I am not able to find the config file. Can you please suggest me the location of config.json file ?

Comment: @RamashankerTripathi The location is in the answer. I'm not sure how I could be any clearer.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Thanks for reply. Actually my Docker installation directory does not contains config.json file.

Comment: @RamashankerTripathi `~/.docker` means `.docker` in your home directory. Try `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\.docker`

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Thanks a lot !! I was searching for it at wrong place. This was really helpful.

Comment: I had to remove "credsStore": "desktop", but it worked afterwards!

Comment: I always need to remove this file when I re-build my kunernetes machine on mac. It gets regenerated so no problem there...

Answer (score 58):

If you use profiles, don't forget to pass `--profile=XXX` to `aws ecr get-login`.

Comment: There has just been an update where get-login was removed from AWS, instead use get-login-password: `sudo docker login -u AWS -p $(aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-north-1 --profile <profile>) <account id>.dkr.ecr.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com`. Dont forget to remove the --profile flag if using default credentials.

Answer (score 33):

I had this issue as well. What happened with me was I forgot to run the command that was returned to me after I ran

```
aws ecr get-login --region ap-southeast-2
```

This command returned a big blob, which includes the `docker login` command right there! I didn't realise. It should return something like this:

```
docker login -u AWS -p <your_token_which_is_massive> -e none <your_aws_url>
```

Copy and paste this command & then run your docker push command which looks something like this:

```
docker push 8888888.blah.blah.ap-southwest-1.amazonaws.com/dockerfilename
```

Comment: I had no idea what that blob response was so I ignored it. haha. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 16):

This should have worked even without opening up the permissions. See the documentation: [Private Registry Authentication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth.html).

[Edit: actually, I had permissions problems too when doing a second test. See [Docker push to AWS ECR private repo failing with malformed JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423873/docker-push-to-aws-ecr-private-repo-failing-with-malformed-json)).]

Nevertheless I had the same problem; I don't know why, but I successfully used the more long-winded auth mechanism described in the docs for [get-authorization-token](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-authorization-token.html)

AWS CLI and Docker versions:

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.9.17 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.16.0-38-generic botocore/1.3.17
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5
```

Get the auth token ('docker password').

```
aws ecr get-authorization-token --region us-east-1 --output text \
    --query authorizationData[].authorizationToken | base64 -d | cut -d: -f2
```

Note: My ~/.aws/config specifies a different default region, so I needed to explicitly set `--region us-east-1`.

Log in interactively (change `############` to your AWS account id):

```
docker login -u AWS https://############.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
password: <paste the very long password from above>
email: <I left this blank>
```

Push an image (assuming you've made a docker image `test`):

```
docker tag test:latest ############.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test:latest
docker push ############.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test:latest
The push refers to a repository [910732017890.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test] (len: 1)
d5122f58a2e1: Pushed 
7bddbca3b908: Pushed 
latest: digest: sha256:bc0b521fd398bd1a2ef58a289dcb910334608723fd570e7bddb36eacd0060363 size: 4378
```

Comment: How did you paste the very long password??? Mine is several lines. I'm using the Windows Docker Quickstart Terminal, which doesn't seem to have good copy/paste capability, or maybe I just can't figure it out.

Comment: To anybody else wondering, I just had to mark-and-copy the whole thing, including whitespace, and then paste that into Notepad. From there, I remove the line breaks, and recopy everything, and only *then* can I paste into the terminal command line. That worked.

Comment: If you're using PowerShell, go to Properties > Options tab and select "Enable line wrapping selection". That way, you can click and drag to select the wrapped lines without having to manually copying into Notepad, deleting new lines etc.

Comment: I haven't touched a windows machine in almost 10 years, but you could always pipe stdout to a file: `aws ecr get-authorization-token > config.json` and then open it in your favorite text editor to copy and paste at will

Comment: Not seeing many other Linux machine responses. I'm on Arch and my solution ended up being to install ecr-credential-helper. Follow their instruction to edit ~/.docker/config.json. Then perform a docker push.

Answer (score 16):

Try with:

```
eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email | sed 's|https://||')
```

before push.

Comment: I got this `no basic auth credentials

Invalid IPv6 URL`

Answer (score 14):

If it helps anyone...

My problem was that I had to use the `--profile` option in order to authenticate with the proper profile from the credentials file.

Next, I had ommitted the `--region [region_name]` command, which also gave the "no basic auth credentials" error.

The solution for me was changing my command from this:

`aws ecr get-login`

To this:

`aws --profile [profile_name] ecr get-login --region [region_name]`

Example:

`aws --profile foo ecr get-login --region us-east-1`

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: You saved me! I was using my aws profile like this,
`AWS_PROFILE=myprofile aws ecr get-login` and it didn't work but introducing the aws profile with `--profile` argument makes the trick!

Answer (score 9):

I experienced the same issue.

Generating new AWS credentials (access keys) and reconfiguring AWS CLI with new credentials resolved the problem.

Earlier, `aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1` generated docker login command with invalid EC registry URL.

Comment: Same happened to me. Thanks!

Comment: This was my problem. I had a different AWS CLI credentials stored in the ~/.aws/credentials than the aws I was managing. Recreated new credentials and setting that worked.

Answer (score 9):

There's a known bug in the wincred credential manager on Windows. Removing 'https://' from the generated login command solves this.

```
docker login -u AWS -p <password> <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com
```

instead of

```
docker login -u AWS -p <password> https://<aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com
```

See also [the troubleshooting page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/common-errors-docker.html#error-403).

Answer (score 7):

Docker CLI doesn't support native IAM authentication methods. To [authenticate and authorize Docker push and pull requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/registry_auth.html) follow this step.

**Step - 1**

Check whether aws credentials properly configured or not. To configure AWS credentials run the following command and give your aws credentials.

```
aws configure
```

**step - 2**

you can authenticate Docker to an Amazon ECR private registry with get-login-password (recommended)

linux and msc

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region <your region> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<your region>.amazonaws.com
```

for windows

```
(Get-ECRLoginCommand).Password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.<your region>.amazonaws.com
```

or

you can also use --get-login method (but expose credentials) (not recommended).

for linux and mac

```
$(aws ecr get-login --region <your region> --no-include-email)
```

for windows

```
Invoke-Expression -Command (Get-ECRLoginCommand -Region <your region>).Command
```

if you got Login Succeeded then you are good to go. else refer [aws docs for error](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/common-errors-docker.html)

**step - 3**

[Push your image to repo](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-push-ecr-image.html)

1. Tag your image

   docker tag  <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr..amazonaws.com/my-web-app
2. Push your image with following command.

   docker push <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr..amazonaws.com/my-web-app

> Note: this is token based login and the generated authorize token
> valid only for 12H

Answer (score 6):

1. Make sure you have created the ECR registry first.
   Then as per the ECR Push Command Instructions, cut and paste the following commands
2. Execute the docker login command (eval on Mac/Linux skips the cut-and-paste)
   `eval $(aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1)`
   add --profile if you use multiple AWS Accounts
   `eval $(aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1 --profile your-profile)`
3. `docker build -t image-name .`
4. `docker tag image-name:latest ############.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/image-name:latest`
5. `docker push ############.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/image-name:latest`

In case of error, *make sure you run all the commands again!* The credentials you get using `aws ecr get-login` are temporary and will expire.

Comment: where do I find out what to put for `your-profile`?

Comment: You can leave it out if you are using the default profile

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to not use the default profile.  I figured it out though, extra profiles can be entered in the `~/.aws/config` and `~/.aws/credentials` files.

Answer (score 6):

On **Windows** in **PowerShell**, use:

```
Invoke-Expression $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email)
```

Comment: this is still relevant

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue with a different cause:  I needed to push to a registry not associated with my AWS Account (a client's ECR registry).  The client had granted me access under the Permissions tab for the registry, by adding my IAM id (e.g., `arn:aws:iam::{AWS ACCT #}:user/{Username}`) as a Principal.  I tried to login with the usual steps:

```
$(aws ecr get-login --region us-west-2 --profile profilename)
docker push {Client AWS ACCT #}.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/imagename:latest
```

Which of course resulted in `no basic auth credentials`.  [As it turns out](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ECR_AWSCLI.html), `aws ecr get-login` logs you in to the ECR *for the registry associated your login*, which makes sense in retrospect.  The solution is to tell `aws ecr get-login` which registry(s) you want to log in to.

```
$(aws ecr get-login --region us-west-2 --profile profilename --registry-ids {Client AWS ACCT #})
```

After that, `docker push` works just fine.

Comment: this makes sense. But what should you pass in the `--profile` ? I have a personal account but I am trying to push to a company account. In other words, where do I find `profilename`

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă you should only be including that if you are using named profiles. See here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html

Comment: @Sergio: The link you've provided is no longer working.

Comment: Should be here now: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/

"You can configure a named profile using the --profile argument." and then later in that same page "aws configure [--profile profile-name]".

Answer (score 5):

In my case, after running `aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region *****`, I just copied the output of that command with is of the form `docker login -u *** -p ************`, and you paste it in the prompt. The pushing went ahead.

Answer (score 5):

There has just been an update where get-login was removed from AWS, instead use get-login-password:

```
sudo docker login -u AWS -p $(aws ecr get-login-password --region <region> - 
-profile <profile>) <account id>.dkr.ecr.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com
```

Dont forget to remove the --profile flag if using default credentials

Answer (score 4):

The AWS documents tell you to execute the following command (for ap-southeast-2 region)

```
aws ecr get-login --region ap-southeast-2
```

When I bumped into this issue, it wasn't clear to me based on that docs that you need to enter the result of this command into the terminal and execute it.

Fix that worked for me to was to copy the result to the clipboard with

```
aws ecr get-login --region ap-southeast-2 | pbcopy
```

Paste the result into the command line and execute it

Answer (score 4):

After run this command:

`(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2)`

just run the docker login command from the output

`docker login -u AWS -p epJ....`

is the way that docker login into ECR

Answer (score 3):

The docker command given by aws-cli is little off...

When using docker login, docker will save a server:key pair either in your keychain or ~/.docker/config.json file

If it saves the key under `https://7272727.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` the lookup for the key during push will fail because docker will be looking for a server named `7272727.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` not `https://7272727.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.

Use the following command to login:

```
eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1 --profile yourprofile | sed 's|https://||')
```

Once you run the command you will get `'Login Succeeded'` message and then you are good 
after that your push command should work

Answer (score 3):

This error generally gets thrown if ecr login has failed. I am using windows system and I used "Powershell" in Administrator mode to login to ecr first.

```
Invoke-Expression $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email)
```

This should output "Login succeeded".

Comment: thank you! why did this help? i was already logging in using saml2aws.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and the mistake I did was using the wrong repo path

eg: `docker push xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/jenkins:latest`

In the above path this is where I've done the mistake: In `"dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"` instead of `"west"`. I was using "`east"`. Once I corrected my mistake, I was able to push the image successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Following command works for me:

```
sudo $(aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1 --no-include-email)
```

And Then I run these commands:

```
sudo docker tag e9ae3c220b23(image_id) aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/my-web-app

sudo docker push aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/my-web-app
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a very simple way to push docker images to ECR: [Amazon ECR Docker Credential Helper](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper). Just install it according to the provided guide, update your `~/.docker/config.json` as the following:

```
{
    "credsStore": "ecr-login"
}
```

and you will be able to push/pull your images without `docker login`.

Comment: I got the same error after following the instructions in this article.

Comment: Worked for me after installing the helper plugin.

Answer (score 2):

## For Mac OSX

### TL;DR Make sure your "auths" key matches your credential store key exactly

- Check your docker config:

`cat ~/.docker/config.json`

Sample Result:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "https://55511155511.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": {}
    },
    "HttpHeaders": {
        "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/19.03.5 (darwin)"
    },
    "credsStore": "osxkeychain"
}
```

Notice that the "auths" value is an empty object and docker is using a credential store "osxkeychain".

- Open Mac's "Keychain Access" app and find the name "Docker Credentials"

[image]

Notice the `Where:` field

- Make sure the `auths` key in `~/.docker/config.json` matches the `Where:` field in Keychain Access.

If the `auths` key in ~/.docker/config.json does NOT match they `Where:` field in the keychain, you may get a `Login Succeeded` from `docker login...` but still get
`ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: Get https://55511155511.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/path/to/image/latest: no basic auth credentials` when you try to pull.

In my case, I needed to add `https://`

**Original**

```
    "auths": {
        "55511155511.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": {}
    },
```

**Fixed**

```
    "auths": {
        "https://55511155511.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": {}
    },
```

Comment: The docker pull on ubuntu started working only after I added the `https://` to `auths`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to this as in case someone out there is suffering from never Reading The F Manual like me
I followed all the suggested steps from above such as

```sh
aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

And always got the no basic auth credentials
I had created a registry named

```sh
123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my.registry.com/namespace
```

and was trying to push an image  called alpine:latest

```sh
123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my.registry.com/namespace/alpine:latest
2c6e8b76de: Preparing
9d4cb0c1e9: Preparing
1ca55f6ab4: Preparing
b6fd41c05e: Waiting
ad44a79b33: Waiting
2ce3c1888d: Waiting
no basic auth credentials
```

Silly mistake on my behalf as I must create a registry in ecr using the full container path.
I created a new registry using the full container path, not ending on the namespace

```sh
123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my.registry.com/namespace/alpine
```

and low and behold pushing to

```sh
123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my.registry.com/namespace/alpine:latest 
The push refers to repository [123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my.registry.com/namespace/alpine]
0c8667b5b: Pushed
730460948: Pushed
1.0: digest: sha256:e1f814f3818efea45267ebfb4918088a26a18c size: 7
```

works just fine

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well running on OSX.  I saw Oliver Salzburg's response and checked my ~/.docker/config.json. It had multiple authorization credentials inside it from the different AWS accounts I have.  I deleted the file and after running get-login again it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use the correct region in `aws ecr get-login`, it must match the region in which your repository is created.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was having multiple AWS credentials; default and dev. Since I was trying to deploy to dev this worked:

```
$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-1 --profile dev | sed 's|https://||')
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, Debian 9, Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a:

`$(aws ecr get-login | sed 's| -e none | |g')`

Answer (score 1):

If you use multiple profiles and you need to login to a profile that is not your default one, you need to login with this command:

```
$(AWS_PROFILE=<YOUR PROFILE> aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the user with which you are running Docker locally is the one which you use to eventually push the image. For me running with sudo caused the issue. Removing sudo from the command solved it. Hope this helps and saves someone`s time and nobody makes this same dumb mistake again. Below is the output for your reference.

```
sudo docker push {your-account-id}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/{repository-name}:{tag-name}
The push refers to repository [{your-account-id}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/{repository-name}]
f13afaa342eb: Preparing
d01b75ce3235: Preparing
7eaa58141607: Preparing
519e8c5b2557: Preparing
15d4a3a33fec: Preparing
fdbbf41b1ab8: Waiting
4b88ecda5399: Waiting
e23a8e1e773f: Waiting
6623e2cc11cd: Waiting
no basic auth credentials
```

Running without the sudo worked perfectly fine

```
docker push {your-account-id}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/{repository-name}:{tag-name}
The push refers to repository [{your-account-id}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/{repository-name}]
f13afaa342eb: Pushed
d01b75ce3235: Pushed
7eaa58141607: Pushed
519e8c5b2557: Pushed
15d4a3a33fec: Pushed
fdbbf41b1ab8: Pushed
4b88ecda5399: Pushed
e23a8e1e773f: Pushed
6623e2cc11cd: Pushed
{tag-name}: digest: sha256:5ceaa5bf7605559582960b6d56a8eece9486ce0950bca9dd63a0dcd38a520bf0 size: 4293
```

Comment: I had the exact same problem! Thank you! removing sudo worked, with sudo added, it wasn't... weird thing!

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same. Please follow the below steps -

1. aws configure (configure with your credentials)
2. If you have created the ECR repository, in console you can find a button with "view push commands". You get three commands there and will be able to push. Else, here are below three commands.
3. aws ecr get-login-password --region  | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin .dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
4. build your docker image - docker build -t  .
5. docker tag :latest .dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/:latest
6. docker push .dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/:latest

Please Note - in .dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com, the region would be your default region. It is us-west-2 for me hence the same.

Hope this saves your time.

Answer (score 0):

we also encounter this issue today and tried everything mentionned in this post (except generating AWS credentials).

We finally solved the problem by simply upgrading Docker, then the push worked.

The problem was encountered with Docker 1.10.x and was solved with Docker 1.11.x.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are isolating AWS Accounts for CI/CD purpose and having one ECR repository shared among multiple AWS Accounts, you might need to change the `~/.docker/config.json` manually.

Let's say you have these setups:

1. ECR is owned by AWS Account ID `00000000000000`
2. CI server is owned by AWS Account ID `99999999999999`

If you call `aws ecr get-login --region us-west-2 | bash` within your CI server, docker will generate temporary credentials in `~/.docker/config.json`.

```
{
  "auths": {
    "https://99999999999999.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com": {
      "auth": "long-token.."
    }
  }
}
```

But you want to point to the ECR's account, so you need to change the hostname.

```
{
  "auths": {
    "https://00000000000000.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com": {
      "auth": "long-token.."
    }
  }
}
```

Note this situation relies how you form IAM user / policy to allow ECR access.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you have logged in using correct credentials, See the offical error description and checks here

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/common-errors-docker.html

Fixing "no basic authentication" is described in the link

Answer (score 0):

```
aws ecr get-login --region us-west-1 --no-include-email
```

This command gives me correct command to login. If you dont use "--no-include-email",it will throw another error. Output of the above command looks like this docker login -u AWS -p **********************very big******. Copy that and execute it. Now it will show "Login Succeeded". Now you can push your image to ECR.

Make sure that your AMI rule has the permission for the user you tried to login.

Answer (score 0):

That error message is coming from docker and it not necessarily related to AWS as I have gotten same error when not using AWS ... its just saying docker is not getting authorization to proceed from whatever source of auth it happens to be using

In my case, in test I removed directory  ~/.docker  and got that error ... after I bounced my local docker registry then docker push was fine

Answer (score 0):

In my case (and probably in all cases), this error resulted from having multiple AWS accounts. So, AWS ECR is not using the right aws credentials assosciated with the aws account.

I tried multiple solutions mentioned here, but did not succeed. **It worked after using tokens instead of username and password**. I got it working following the instructions here. https://btburnett.com/2017/01/docker-login-for-amazon-aws-ecr-using-windows-powershell.html

Answer (score 0):

I add the region option and everything works then fine for me:

```
aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-3
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted an answer to this on the Docker forums. In my case the issue was that the centos "docker" was not equivalent to Docker CE and therefore failed with:

> no basic auth

I simply fixed by installing "docker-ce" on centos.

Reference: https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-push-to-ecr-failing-with-no-basic-auth-credentials/17358/30

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and fixed it with this command. It works for me, please update it as per your account.
This is for Ubuntu machine where AWS-CLI needs to be installed with Docker

```
algorithm_name='multi-model-xgboost'

account=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query Account --output text)

# Get the region defined in the current configuration
region=$(aws configure get region)

aws ecr get-login-password --region ${region} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${account}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com/${algorithm_name}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I installed `aws-credentials-helper` by downloading the repo and compiling it myself. I discovered that I used the wrong compile command: `make docker` instead of `make docker TARGET_GOOS=darwin` (I'm on Mac). The resulting `bin/local/docker-credential-ecr-login` was not executable initially.

Answer (score 0):

`I had to run aws ecr get-login-password due to aws cli deprecating the get-login command.`

`Also in this version the username is forced to be hard coded as AWS.`

`Here was the command that worked for aws-cli/2.0.58.`

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region region_y | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin account_x.dkr.ecr.region_y.amazonaws.com
```

Login Succeeded

Answer (score 0):

On Windows system,  you have to make empty the following file `~/.docker/config.json` and then run again the below script

```
aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region ap-southeast-1 --profile [profile_name]
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS depricated get-login instead of that please use following command

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region <region> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <ecr-repo-full-path>
```

example

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region ap-south-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 607348619222.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down. Simple concise, and its the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the current user is added to the docker group (ie. you aren't prefixing docker commands with sudo eg.  `sudo docker push.....` ).

So, run

```
  sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

See attached,[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
## If you are using 2FA in AWS : To authenticate Docker and AWS
```

1. Open Ubuntu shell or similar. (Not Windows CMD or Powershell)
2. Run the command down below
   `aws sts get-session-token --serial-number "User ARN" --token-code "code_from_authenticator"`
3. create temp (mfa) profile in "C:\Users\user.aws\credentials" and use the output from number 2.

   - [mfa]
   - aws_access_key_id = xxxx
   - aws_secret_access_key =xxxx
   - aws_session_token = xxx
   - region = your region
4. aws ecr get-login --profile mfa
5. copy the output from 4. and run login command (delete the -e None) part

   - Receive Successful Login!
6. run the aws push commands

Answer (score 0):

At least as of 2023, there is a helpful "**View push commands**" button in the **AWS console** page for the **ECR private repositories**, next to the other Actions for your repository. Clicking the button will open the popup dialog which lists all the prepopulated Docker commands, required to push the image to the repo.

Answer (score -1):

Simply run whatever returned in step one would fix the issue.