# Unable to push docker image to Openshift Origin Docker registry

Tags: docker, openshift, docker-registry, openshift-origin

I was trying to deploy a docker image I have created via Openshift. I followed the instructions in: [http://www.opensourcerers.org/importing-an-external-docker-image-into-red-hat-openshift-v3/](http://www.opensourcerers.org/)

However, as I tried to push my docker image to the Openshift registry, it did not succeed, as shown below

> [root@mymachine ~]# docker push
> 172.30.155.111:5000/default/mycostumedaemon
>
> The push refers to a repository
> [172.30.155.111:5000/default/mycostumedaemon]
>
> 0a4a35d557a6: Preparing
>
> 025eba1692ec: Preparing
>
> 5332a889b228: Preparing
>
> e7b287e8074b: Waiting
>
> 149636c85012: Waiting
>
> f96222d75c55: Waiting
>
> **no basic auth credentials**

Following are the docker version and openshift versions:

> [root@mymachine ~]# docker --version
>
> Docker version 1.11.0, build 4dc5990
>
> [root@mymachine ~]# oc version
>
> oc v1.2.0
>
> kubernetes v1.2.0-36-g4a3f9c5

Could someone help me out with this? Not sure what it means by "**no basic auth credentials**" since the openshift user and server user are root users with all privileges.

Comment: please check if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689445/cant-push-image-to-amazon-ecr-fails-with-no-basic-auth-credentials

Comment: nope.. it didn't help me solve the issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After performing `oc login` to authenticate on your cluster you have to go inside your default project

```
$ oc project default
```

Check the service ip of your registry:

```
$ oc get svc

NAME              CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                   AGE
docker-registry   172.30.xx.220   <none>        5000/TCP                  76d
kubernetes        172.30.0.1       <none>        443/TCP,53/UDP,53/TCP     76d
router            172.30.xx.xx     <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP,1936/TCP   76d
```

Check your token:

```
$ oc whoami -t
trSZhNVi8F_N3Pxxx
```

Now you can authenticate on your registry:

```
docker login -u test -e any@mail.com -p trSZhNVi8F_N3Pxxx 172.30.xx.220:5000
WARNING: login credentials saved in /root/.docker/config.json
Login Succeeded
```

Answer (score 0):

One stroke login:

```
docker login -u developer -p $(oc whoami -t) $(oc registry info)
```