# Docker login auth token

Tags: docker, docker-compose, macos-sierra, dockerhub, codeship

I'm trying to get `docker login` auth from `~/.docker/config.json` file.
But I can't see `auth` token in my `config.json` file.
Here is my docker version.

```
docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Tue Mar 28 00:40:02 2017
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Fri Mar 24 00:00:50 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

When I run `cat ~/.docker/config.json` then what I can see is

```
cat .docker/config.json
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
    },
    "credsStore": "osxkeychain"
}%
```

According to Codeship [documentation](https://documentation.codeship.com/pro/getting-started/getting-started-part-three/#encrypted-credentials) I should have to see

```
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
            "auth": "auth_key",
            "email": "email"
        }
    }
}
```

Can I disable storing my authkey in keychain?

I really need to get `auth_key`, how can I get that?

Thank you

Comment: The simplest way to solve that is to install somewhere old version of docker inside of ubuntu and generate token there. Not offering it as answer as it's ugly. But works.

Comment: Check your Keychain Access App for a matching key
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59363993/4418836

Answer (score 111):

Auth is simply a base64 encoded 'username:password' string. You can get it with the following command:

```
echo -n 'username:password' | base64
```

Comment: I think it is a easiest way to generate auth token on mac os which by default store docker credentials on mac os keychain...

Comment: Depending on the `base64` implementation you may have to disable line wrapping by using the `-w` flag: `base64 -w 0`.

Answer (score 26):

If you are using Kubernetes, and you need it for creating the registry password just run:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry --dry-run=true docker-regcred \
--docker-server=https://index.docker.io/v1/ \
--docker-username=xxx \
--docker-password=xxx \
--docker-email=yourmail@yourdomain.com \
--namespace=xxx \
-o yaml > docker-secret.yaml
```

This will create `docker-secret.yaml` with your JSON there.
if you dont include `--dry-run=client` and `-o yaml > docker-secret.yaml` It will create the k8s secret.

Comment: Note this will expose your password to your shell history and the kubectl session...

Comment: `--dry-run=true is deprecated (boolean value) and can be replaced with --dry-run=client.` Works after the change

Answer (score 12):

Using [credential store](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store) is more secure than storing base64 encoded credentials in `config.json` file. In your case docker is using the native keychain of the Mac OS (i.e. osxkeychain) as the credential store.

Now for the problem of getting credentials from the `osxkeychain` you can use [docker-credential-helpers](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers).

Steps to get the credential (in terminal):

1. Download the [latest](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases) release.
2. Extract and move it to `/usr/local/bin` or add its path to the `$PATH` variable. So that you are able to access it globally.
3. Execute this command in terminal `echo "<server-url>" | docker-credential-osxkeychain get`. In case you want to find out the `server-url` use this command `docker-credential-osxkeychain list`.

Get credential in go code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    osx "github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/client"
)

func main() {

    p := osx.NewShellProgramFunc("docker-credential-osxkeychain")

    creds, err := osx.Get(p, "server-url")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Got credentials for user `%s` in `%s` with secret `%s` \n", creds.Username, creds.ServerURL, creds.Secret)
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21094523)

Comment: @zgue thank you for the review, I elaborated my answer.

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue too; I fixed it by deleting the `"credsStore"` key from that JSON file. The next time I ran `docker login`, it gave me a warning but saved the auth token into that file.

Here's my docker version:

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.4
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.3
 Git commit:        9013bf5
 Built:             Wed Oct 30 21:32:58 2019
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.4
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.10
  Git commit:       9013bf583a
  Built:            Fri Oct 18 15:55:51 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.10
  GitCommit:        b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8+dev
  GitCommit:        3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Answer (score 7):

using macos，you need write a config.json file, template like this:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "hub.xxx.com": {
            "username": "xxx",
            "password": "xxx",
            "email": "xxx",
            "auth": "base64(username:password)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP knows he needs to write a config file. He is asking how to automatically write to the config file when doing docker login.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the answer [from Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45671103/1202500), I've created a small "one liner" that can easily be given to users as a copy-paste instruction:

```sh
echo -en "------\nPlease enter Docker registry login:\nUsername: "; \
    read regusername; \
    echo -n "Password: "; \
    read -s regpassword; \
    echo""; \
    echo -n "Auth Token: "; \
    echo -n "$regusername:$regpassword" | base64; \
    unset regpassword; \
    unset regusername;
```

Or the "real" one-liner:

```sh
echo -en "------\nPlease enter Docker registry login:\nUsername: "; read regusername; echo -n "Password: "; read -s regpassword; echo""; echo -n "Auth Token: "; echo -n "$regusername:$regpassword" | base64; unset regpassword; unset regusername;
```

Advantage over the simple base64-command: It doesn't display the password input, so you can't find the clear password in the bash history. It also prints clear instructions to the user.

Tested on:

- MacOS in zsh and bash
- Ubuntu in bash

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the `config.json` file and log-in again fixed the issue for me.