# Error in mesos slave when trying to pull image from ECR

Tags: docker, mesos, amazon-ecr

Configuring a mesos slave to use amazon ECR gives the following error when it receives a job:

> Unsupported auth-scheme: BASIC

Does this look familiar to anyone ? I'm running the slave pointed to my user's docker config json file, which i updated by issuing a docker login beforehand.

Comment: Can you show your configuration? How do you obtain [authentication token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34692206/1387612).

Comment: I solved it in the mean time, i was just stupid. I'll post an answer below

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was my bad. I didn't modify the application that started this job to change the docker image name to include the registry as well.